# Code folds are automatically opened when cursor moves over them in VS Code Vim. How can I prevent this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I like to fold code in the VS Code editor, but even when I fold some code blocks, they are opened when I move over them with my cursor using `j / k` using the VS Code Vim extension. How can I protect my code folds from automatically opening like this?

Comment: Are you using a [Vim extension by any chance](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1004)? Or is this happening in regular VSCode?

Comment: I'm using visual studio code vim extension.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It looks like this is an [issue many people have had for a while](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/1552), and the solution is to do the following ([original source](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#-faq)):

1. Open up your user settings. On windows the shortcut is
   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>
2. Search for `vim.foldfix` and check the checkbox so the setting is set to `true`.

Alternatively, open your `settings.json` file by opening the command palette (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), select **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)**, then add the following line: `"vim.foldfix": true`

Now the folds should no longer automatically expand when you scroll past them with <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd>.

Be aware that this is a hack because of [various problems with VS Code itself](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22276) that make fixing this difficult.

Comment: same problem happened to me. Automatically my cursor up and down when I following upper way.

Comment: Did this solve your problem, or are you saying it's still not working? I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: It had been worked in some manner, but the side effect generated. The side effect is overwhelming so I  just toggled the option to false. My original problem was folded codes are automatically opened when I cursor crossing down to these block, But when I toggled the option as true, my cursor cannot work properly when I push 'J' or 'K'.

Comment: I see. Hopefully they will add a proper fix soon, but it might be a while.

Comment: Only works with "J" "K", folds still open with using <C-d>, and other movements.

Comment: Is one of the side effects the ctrl-d, ctrl-u, ctrl-f, ctrl-b will not work if the cursor were to land in one of the collapsed folds?

Comment: It works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

For people who want to prevent this without implementing the hacking way suggested by the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50892839/14923262), you can simply use [`gj`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#gj) & [`gk`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#gk) to navigate.

Furthermore, if `gj` & `gk` is not convenient for you, [a little mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713982/14923262) might help.

Comment: Really helpful answer. Also thanks for linking to other issue for more context