# How to walk in vim without expanding the code that I collapsed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

I am using <kbd>zc</kbd> to collapse and <kbd>zo</kbd> to expand the code in vim.
My problem is that when I walk through the code using <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd>. code that is collapsed is got expand. I want to walk through collapsed code. what can I do?

I am using vim in VScode. But the same is true if I use vim in the terminal.

Comment: This is strange since this doesn't happen to me when I run vim in the terminal - although using `h` and `l` does expand a fold (I assume that's intended behaviour though). Could you add your vim version and be sure to include any settings from your .vimrc that relate to vim's folding behaviour

Comment: I have been using `vim` and `gvim` for more than 10 years and I agree with what mattb says: expending folds after `j` and `k` is strange and unusual side-effect.

Comment: What does `:set foldclose?` shows in your vim?

Comment: @dlmeetei `:set foldclose?` give output `foldclose=`  then I write `:set foldclose=all` now it's working fine thanks.

Comment: For VScode I get the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888475/code-folds-are-automatically-opened-when-cursor-moves-over-them-in-vs-code-vim).

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in neovim(with Astro) for me, but not in **vscode** where it has the same problem. I have to use `gj` and `gh` so it moves by line on the `screen` instead of `file`.

you can also remap in your config if needed:

```
:nnoremap j gj
:nnoremap k gk
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888475/code-folds-are-automatically-opened-when-cursor-moves-over-them-in-vs-code-vim)

Comment: @ShrimanKeshri the answer you point to is a better way to do it. Please add it as a separate answer