# Visual Studio Code: Vim - jumping lines counts the lines in folded code block

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using the Vim emulator for VSC, if I want to jump lines, let's say 10 lines down by entering `10j<Enter>`, *if* there is a folded code block within those 10 lines, it will open the code block and go to the 10th line *overall*.

I am not referring to folded code blocks opening upon *scrolling* down / up your code, by just pressing `j` or `k`, as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888475/code-folds-are-automatically-opened-when-cursor-moves-over-them-in-vs-code-vim). I have the "Vim: Foldfix" checked within my preferences.

**NOTE:** regular Vim does not include lines within the folded blocks when jumping multiple lines at once, and that is the response I am looking for.