# Locking a Fold in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, fold

I use folding constantly but it seems to be missing one key feature. There are some parts of my code that are rather long that I'm constantly having to scroll past. Having formatting on save often unfolds sections that I rarely if ever want unfolded. Is there a way to lock certain folds so that it takes more than the standard actions to unfold?

For instance, when working in html, I have json scripts for google meta information that are long. They are mostly boilerplate but each page needs several custom changes. I want to fold and lock this so that it only unfolds when I specifically want to make changes to that script. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I've searched help files and website tips but haven't found any references.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888475/code-folds-are-automatically-opened-when-cursor-moves-over-them-in-vs-code-vim